# $.ajax not returning data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to POST data back to the server and get a dataset back.  What I am getting back instead is the HTML for the whole page *AND* it is not kicking off the Action in my Controller.  And yes - JQuery is still confusing to me.

The code I currently have is:

```
function updateNavIndex(pageIndex) {
    var filters = $("form").serialize();
    var productGroup = $("#valProductGroup").attr('title');
    var productType = $("#valProductType").attr('title');
    var itemsPerPage = $("#ItemsPerPage").val();

    $.ajax({ path: "/CatalogAjaxController/UpdateNavigation"
          , type: "POST"
          , data: "{ productGroup: " + productGroup + ", productType: " + productType + ", itemsPerPage: " + itemsPerPage + ", pageIndex: " + pageIndex + ", filters: " + filters + "}"
          , success: function(data) { handleMenuData(data); }
    });
    $.ajax({ path: "/CatalogAjaxController/UpdateProducts"
          , type: "POST"
          , data: "{ productGroup: " + productGroup + ", productType: " + productType + ", itemsPerPage: " + itemsPerPage + ", pageIndex: " + pageIndex + ", filters: " + filters + "}"
          , success: function(data) { handleProductData(data); }
    });
}
```

The callback function is tripping and the function definition looks like:

```
function handleMenuData(data) {
    $("#navigation ul").remove();
    }
```

At this point the "data" variable has the Page HTML in it.  (And like I said, the Action did not fire off.)  I am thinking that I should not be calling the $ajax function directly but using a var function definition.  Something like:

```
var retrieveMenuData = function(path, productGroup, productType, itemsPerPage, pageIndex, filter, fnHandleCallback) {
    $.ajax( path
          , type
          , { productGroup: productGroup, productType: productType, itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage, pageIndex: pageIndex, filter: filter }
          , function(data) { fnHandleCallback(data); });
};
```

I'm not sure if I have it defined correctly or how to call it correctly.  ANy help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

also, you've got some odd quotes in there.. the syntax for `data:` is more like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "bin/login.php",
    data:{data1: var1,data2: var2},
    success: function(data) {
        }
     });
```

Comment: Ah, good point... it doesn't make a lot of sense to quote JSON in javascript... JSON is Javscript Object Notation, after all.

Comment: I am using the post at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799404/ajax-and-mvc-c" and I am still getting the error "data is undefined" - where data is supposed to be the return from the Controller.Action method.

Comment: My var function definition lookls like:  
var retrieveData2 = function(path, productGroup, productType, itemsPerPage, pageIndex, filters, fnHandleCallback) {
$.getJSON(path
, { productGroup: productGroup, productType: productType, itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage, pageIndex: pageIndex, filter: filter }
, function(data) { fnHandleCallback(data); });
};  

When I call it is when I get the error.  My call looks like:  
retrieveData2("/CatalogAjaxController/UpdateNavigation", productGroup, productType, itemsPerPage, pageIndex, filters, handleMenuData(data));

*confused*

Comment: I always thought the contentType attribute was mandatory! Is it mandatory because I don't see you using in the above code!

Comment: No, contentType defaults to application/x-www-form-urlencoded (the encoding for a GET/POST query string).

Answer (score 3):

The solution may be pretty simple.

You're using `path:` where it should have `url:`

Source: [jQuery.ajax options list](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options)